# Workflow statuses (9-14)

Tags: workflow

I have theoretical question, according to [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514224%28office.12%29.aspx#MOSS2007DevWorkflowSolutions_SettingOutcomeValues) the first 15 values in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowStatus enumeration are reserved by Windows SharePoint Services for internal use.

I found out that the developers know this table

0 - NotStarted
1 - FailedOnStart
2 - InProgress
3 - ErrorOccurred
4 - StoppedByUser
5 - Completed
6 - FailedOnStartRetrying
7 - ErrorOccurredRetrying
8 - ViewQueryOverflow

but what about 9-14? What these values mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are no official msdn documentation against what lies behind 9-14 status codes for SharePoint workflows , the close understanding would be these codes stands for errors that are not specific to the predefined set of results defined for a workflow in the SharePoint system. They are generally a mix of design level , runtime or external issues that causes the workflows to behave in an unexpected way whose cause cannot be determined by SharePoint so it returns "unknown" for all codes between 9 to 14.

Why SharePoint keeps unknown status codes into different numbers between 9 to 14 and not just maintain a single numeric status code is something which I have seen rarely been discussed anywhere.

You can see this link where the person encountered this "unknown" status code against his workflow and explained briefly the 9-14 status code over [here](http://karteekblog.blogspot.in/2009/11/workflows-unknown-status.html)